# Can an OpenVPN Route over TEST-NET-1 (RFC 5735)

Tags: networking, routes, ip-address, openvpn

## Background

I have a strange use-case where my VPN cannot be on any of the private subnets, but, also cannot use a TAP interface. The machine will be moving through different subnets, and requires access to the entire private address space by design. A single blocked IP would be considered a failure of design.

So, these are all off limits:

- 10.0.0.0/8
- 172.16.0.0/12
- 192.168.0.0/16
- 169.254.0.0/16

In searching for a solution, I came across RFC 5735, which defines:

- 192.0.2.0/24 TEST-NET-1
- 198.51.100.0/24 TEST-NET-2
- 203.0.113.0/24  TEST-NET-3

As:

> For use in documentation and example code.  It is often used in conjunction with domain names
> example.com or example.net in vendor and protocol documentation.  As described in [RFC5737], addresses within this block do not legitimately appear on the public Internet and can be used without any coordination with IANA or an Internet registry.

Which, was a "Jackpot" moment for me and my use case.

## Config

I configured an OpenVPN server as such:

```
local 0.0.0.0
port 443
proto tcp
dev tun
topology subnet
server 203.0.113.0 255.255.255.0 # TEST-NET-3 RFC 5735
push "route 203.0.113.0 255.255.255.0"
...[Snip]...
```

With Client:

```
client
nobind
dev tun
proto tcp
...[Snip]...
```

And ufw rules:

```
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 203.0.113.0/24 -o ens160 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

However, upon running I get `/sbin/ip route add 203.0.113.0/24 via 203.0.113.1 RTNETLINK answers: File exists` in the error logs. While the VPN completes the rest of its connection successfully.

## No connection

Running the following commands:
Server: `sudo python3 -m http.server 80`
Client: `curl -X GET / 203.0.113.1`
Results in:
`curl: (28) Failed to connect to 203.0.113.1 port 80: Connection timed out`

I have tried:

- `/sbin/ip route replace 203.0.113.0/24 dev tun 0` on client and server.
- `/sbin/ip route change 203.0.113.0/24 dev tun 0` on client and server.
- Adding `route 203.0.113.0 255.255.255.0` to the server.
- Adding `push "route 203.0.113.0 255.255.255.0 127.0.0.1"` to server

And none of it seems to work.

Does anyone have any idea how I can force the client to push this traffic over the VPN to my server, instead of to the public IP?

Comment: You need to consult the _[IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml)_, where it explains that addresses for each of those ranges cannot be used for source or destination addresses, and are not forwardable (able to be routed).

Comment: Oh drat. Do you know of any range that could be used for my purpose? Or any workaround for a device that needs a vpn, but also needs to not block access to any internal subnet for networking scanning?

Answer (score 0):

This does actually work!

Just dont forget to allow connections within your firewall. I fixed my config with:

```
sudo ufw allow in on tun0
```

However, 198.18.0.0/15 and 100.64.0.0/10 defined as Benchmarking and Shared address space respectively, may be more appropriate choices, since being able to forward TEST-NET addresses may be considered a bug.

Comment: From the RFC: "_However, Shared Address Space has limitations in its use that the current [RFC1918] private address space does not have. In particular, Shared Address Space can only be used in Service Provider networks or on routing equipment that is able to do address translation across router interfaces when the addresses are identical on two different interfaces._"

Comment: @RonMaupin That's great - It does, however, function. Which, is all I really care about. As long as I don't test a Service Provider Network, I'll be okay.

Comment: OK, but you should be very wary of going against published standards. Remember that the network stack on a device could be decide you are not playing by the rules an refuse to play along. OS updates may also present a future problem.